# Is "submittable" a valid word?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

Is "submittable" a valid word to describe something that is eligible to submit?

Comment: This question is Fair Dinkum!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=submittable&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) says the word is in existence since 1840s with a meaning similar to that which you are asking.

I would say it means "something which can be submitted"

However, a more commonly used word for this is **[submissible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/submissible)**

Some examples of submittable:

> therefore not more than any other submittable to an arbitrary power
>   and extrajudicial proceeding

and

> the discharging of Greenock's heirs to purchase New Wark being neither
>   submitted nor submittable in itself, laying them under a perpetual
>   servitude

and

> It Is contended that, because this net contains an emergency clause,
>   it was not therefore submittable to a vote of the people under the
>   referendum