# Is there a preference between 'submissible' and 'submittable'?

Tags: word-choice

When referring to something that can be submitted, is there a preference between *'submissible'* and *'submittable'*?

If so, does the preference vary by geographic region?

Related: [Is "submittable" a valid word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39525/is-submittable-a-valid-word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are a legal writer, use *submissible*.**

You will find both in a dictionary like the Oxford English Dictionary ([submittable](https://oed.com/view/Entry/242495), [submissible](https://oed.com/view/Entry/192822)) to mean "capable of being submitted"; the only significant difference is that *submissible* can also mean

> (Law) able to be submitted as legal evidence,

a usage supported by legal dictionaries ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/submissible)).

**If you prefer a prescriptivist standard, use *submissible*.**

For example, Bryan Garner marks *submittable* as a "needless variant" in his book *[Garner's Modern English Usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garner%27s_Modern_English_Usage)* (under **submissible**), a phrase that means the second spelling has no significant difference in meaning and thus should be avoided. While the variant is "needless," Garner notes that the ratio of *submissible vs. submittable* in World English is about 5:1.

**Otherwise, use either.**

As noted in the Oxford English Dictionary, both words are in current use.

At least in an Ngram, *submissible* has been on a long and slow decline since the 1950s, at least in Google's corpus, though only recently have they been anywhere close to parity. The chart below is a general corpus search, and searching the American and British corpuses separately didn't yield significant differences ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=submittable%2Csubmissible&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Great answer.  Upvoted and accepted.  Now, I must ask, what about if someone is an *illegal* writer? :) :)